# Build Class Library projects using Azure Devops

Tags: build, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have a solution with 3 class library projects (business logic, data access layers, web service).

I can build the solution in Visual Studio.

However when the build task runs in Azure DevOps, it fails with errors that the namespace or type does not exist. The error  is for one of the class library projects that is dependent on the another.

What could be the issue here?

The second part of this is, when I add a build task for a web application, how can I ensure that the web application can reference the DLLS correctly from the first build of the class library projects solution (in order to build itself correctly)?

Below is excerpt from solution file - the "not found" error relates to the **MatterDBLibrary** project.

```
 Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MatterDBBusinessEntities", "MatterDBBusinessEntities\MatterDBBusinessEntities.csproj", "{EC049257-C855-47DC-A2DF-02910DBC34A3}"
EndProject

    Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MattersDBService", "MattersDBService\MattersDBService.csproj", "{34F4FE24-948B-4EF2-8252-7FDA8430616F}"
EndProject

Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MatterDBLibrary", 
    "MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBLibrary.csproj", "{D76D1BFC-8B1E-4A3F-AC76-3218CA28E5D7}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {34F4FE24-948B-4EF2-8252-7FDA8430616F} = {34F4FE24-948B-4EF2-8252-7FDA8430616F}
        {EC049257-C855-47DC-A2DF-02910DBC34A3} = {EC049257-C855-47DC-A2DF-02910DBC34A3}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

MatterDB references:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MatterDBBusinessEntities\MatterDBBusinessEntities.csproj">
      <Project>{ec049257-c855-47dc-a2df-02910dbc34a3}</Project>
      <Name>MatterDBBusinessEntities</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

MatterDBService references:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MatterDBBusinessEntities\MatterDBBusinessEntities.csproj">
      <Project>{ec049257-c855-47dc-a2df-02910dbc34a3}</Project>
      <Name>MatterDBBusinessEntities</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

The third project (MatterDBBusinessEntities) has no dependency on the above two.

```
##[warning]MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\Fakes\MatterDBBusinessEntities.fakes(0,0): Warning : Some fakes could not be generated. For complete details, set Diagnostic attribute of the Fakes element in this file to 'true' and rebuild the project.
2019-06-24T17:37:09.1641534Z D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\Fakes\MatterDBBusinessEntities.fakes : warning : Some fakes could not be generated. For complete details, set Diagnostic attribute of the Fakes element in this file to 'true' and rebuild the project. [D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBLibrary.csproj]
2019-06-24T17:37:09.2160099Z ResolveAssemblyReferences:
2019-06-24T17:37:09.2160196Z   Primary reference "MatterDBBusinessEntities".
2019-06-24T17:37:09.2161791Z ##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "MatterDBBusinessEntities". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
2019-06-24T17:37:09.2163119Z C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "MatterDBBusinessEntities". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBLibrary.csproj]
2019-06-24T17:37:09.2163318Z           For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
2019-06-24T17:37:09.2163467Z           Considered "..\MatterDBBusinessEntities\bin\Debug\MatterDBBusinessEntities.dll", but it didn't exist.
2019-06-24T17:37:09.2163632Z           For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".

2019-06-24T17:37:09.4347164Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe+ /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll /reference:D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll /reference:"D:\a\1\s\Deals\Phase 3\DEV\ExternalReference\Korzh.EasyQuery.Db.NET45.dll" /reference:"D:\a\1\s\Deals\Phase 3\DEV\ExternalReference\Korzh.EasyQuery.Mvc.NET45.dll" /reference:"D:\a\1\s\Deals\Phase 3\DEV\ExternalReference\Korzh.EasyQuery.NET45.dll" /reference:"D:\a\1\s\Deals\Phase 3\DEV\ExternalReference\MatterDBLibrary.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\External References\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /reference:"D:\a\1\s\Deals\Phase 3\DEV\ExternalReference\Stikeman.Extension.Object.dll" /reference:"D:\a\1\s\Deals\Phase 3\DEV\ExternalReference\Stikeman.Extension.String.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Runtime.Caching.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.ServiceModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Web.Services.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Release\MatterDBLibrary.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /resource:obj\Release\Stikeman.MatterDB.Library.Properties.Resources.resources /target:library /utf8output Constant.cs DataModel\EntityAttributes.cs DataModel\Enum.cs DataModel\Operators.cs DataModel\SavedSearchModel.cs DataModel\SearchModel.cs DataModel\SearchQueryModel.cs ImpersonateManager.cs MatterDBBuilder.cs MatterDBController.cs MatterDBPersistor.cs MatterLockException.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs DataModel\SearchResultModel.cs "Service References\ContactServices\Reference.cs" "Service References\EmployeeServices\Reference.cs" "Service References\EthicalWallServices\Reference.cs" UserNotFoundException.cs Utils.cs "Web References\IntAppServices\Reference.cs" "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
2019-06-24T17:37:09.4348317Z   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
2019-06-24T17:37:10.0330700Z ##[warning]MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\ImpersonateManager.cs(7,40): Warning CS0618: 'SecurityAction.RequestMinimum' is obsolete: 'Assembly level declarative security is obsolete and is no longer enforced by the CLR by default. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.'
2019-06-24T17:37:10.0331697Z ImpersonateManager.cs(7,40): warning CS0618: 'SecurityAction.RequestMinimum' is obsolete: 'Assembly level declarative security is obsolete and is no longer enforced by the CLR by default. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.' [D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBLibrary.csproj]
2019-06-24T17:37:10.0332924Z ##[warning]MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\ImpersonateManager.cs(8,35): Warning CS0618: 'SecurityAction.RequestMinimum' is obsolete: 'Assembly level declarative security is obsolete and is no longer enforced by the CLR by default. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.'
2019-06-24T17:37:10.0333757Z ImpersonateManager.cs(8,35): warning CS0618: 'SecurityAction.RequestMinimum' is obsolete: 'Assembly level declarative security is obsolete and is no longer enforced by the CLR by default. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information.' [D:\a\1\s\MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBLibrary.csproj]
MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\DataModel\SearchQueryModel.cs(1,25): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessEntities' does not exist in the namespace 'Stikeman.MatterDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBBuilder.cs(14,25): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessEntities' does not exist in the namespace 'Stikeman.MatterDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBController.cs(18,31): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessEntities' does not exist in the namespace 'Stikeman.MatterDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBController.cs(17,25): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessEntities' does not exist in the namespace 'Stikeman.MatterDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBPersistor.cs(9,25): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessEntities' does not exist in the namespace 'Stikeman.MatterDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\MatterDBPersistor.cs(10,25): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessEntities' does not exist in the namespace 'Stikeman.MatterDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\DataModel\SearchResultModel.cs(1,25): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BusinessEntities' does not exist in the namespace 'Stikeman.MatterDB' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\DataModel\SearchResultModel.cs(37,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NamedObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\DataModel\SearchQueryModel.cs(41,21): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NamedObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

MattersDB\DEV\MatterDBLibrary\DataModel\SearchQueryModel.cs(152,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NamedObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly the error? can you share the build pipeline?

Comment: Additional log information added.

Answer (score 1):

> However when the build task runs in Azure DevOps, it fails with errors that the namespace or type does not exist. The error is for one of the class library projects that is dependent on the another.

Since one of the class library projects that is dependent on the another, so, to resolve this issue, the best solution is add project reference for the class library project. Then on the build task, select the solution file `.sln` file in the Solution option:

[image]

Then MSBuild/Visual Studio will choose to build the referenced project first based on the reference relationship in the project file,like `<ProjectReference Include="..\TestReferenceApp\TestReferenceApp.csproj">` and copy the output to the directory of the reference project.

> The second part of this is, when I add a build task for a web
>   application, how can I ensure that the web application can reference
>   the DLLS correctly from the first build of the class library projects
>   solution (in order to build itself correctly)?

Just like the answer for the first question, add the project reference to the web application. If adding a reference is limited to you, you could build the class library projects first, then add a [copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the library to the output of web application. Or you can pack the class library project as nuget package, then add this nuget package to the web application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I selected the correct solution in the build task.

Comment: @Perplexed, Thanks your reply. I got it, so, do you have add project reference one project to another project? Could you please share the <ProjectReference> info in the project file .csproj?

Comment: Hi Leo, I have updated the question with this detail. Thx

Comment: @Perplexed, could you please share your build error messages in your question, I need to check the log try to find the reason for this issue.

Comment: According to the latest error info, this error should be for the project `MatterDBLibrary.csproj` and it seems not reference the project `MatterDBBusinessEntities`? So, please try to add project reference to the `MatterDBLibrary.csproj` or you can share the project file of `MatterDBLibrary.csproj`